# Proper way to set up directories in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I've been reading through the documentation, which is great, however I'm still not entirely sure the best way of creating a nested route in NextJS.

In my example I have modules that have nested lessons. Or in other words, my module could be a book and each lesson a chapter.

So, my current thought is to have my pages directory like so:

`pages/modules/[mid]/lessons/[lid]`

Pretty generic route path, but it feels off to create a dir path like this:

```
/Pages
--/modules
----[id].js
----/lessons
------[id].js
```

It seems very very coupled to modules. What happens if I want a different route to lead to lessons or if I make another page that just GETs all lessons regardless of modules. What then?

Would the ex below be a normal/suitable design? Seems a bit messy having all these tucked away places to have lessons appear. I'm sure I'll get a better grip of it soon enough. Just want to make sure I'm not going well off the beaten path.

```
/Pages
--/modules
----[id].js
----/lessons
------[id].js
--/lessons
----index.js
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to nest the entire content of a directory under a route parameter you can name the directory itself between brackets. Then all the content under moduleId directory will receive a module Id.

You can have

/Pages

--[moduleId]

----/lessons

------[id].js